# Derivative of the maximum of a function on a interval

Tags: derivatives, absolute-value

My question is as follows:

Given a function $f: [-h,\infty) \rightarrow \mathcal{R}$ and the maximum function given by

\begin{equation}
\max_{s\in [-h,0]} |f(t+s)|
\end{equation}
for $t\geq0$.

Then I would like to know the absolute value of the derivative with respect $t$ of the above function or at least an upper bound. That is,

\begin{equation}
\left| \frac{d}{dt}\left(  \max_{s\in [-h,0]} |f(t+s)|  \right) \right|
\end{equation}

My hypothesis is that it can be bound as follows

\begin{equation}
\left| \frac{d}{dt}\left(  \max_{s\in [-h,0]} |f(t+s)|  \right) \right| \leq \max_{s\in [-h,0]} \left( \frac{d}{dt}|f(t+s)| \right)
\end{equation}

The idea is that the maximum function can not change faster than the function at the maximum point, but I struggle to formally prove it.

Can anyone suggest me how to prove it? or if there is already a proof.

Thank you.